# How to execute the For n times using a specific column of an excel table in python?

Tags: python, selenium, for-loop

I want to repeat a process by a number from a column of my data. How can I do it using For?

It's something like

| column_repetition |
| --- |
| 2 |
| 2 |
| 3 |

each line of the column_repetition the automation repeats.

```
    for i,  range(column_repetion):
    recebimento=data.iloc[i, data.columns.get_loc('recebimento')]
    item=data.iloc[i, data.columns.get_loc('CODIGO_PRODUTO')]
    ordem=data.iloc[i, data.columns.get_loc('ordem')]
    print("Em andamento smartphone:")
    print(ordem)
    print(item)
    print(recebimento)
driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'//*delQry:value00::content"]').click()
```

Comment: Please update your question with relevant code?

Answer (score 0):

With the information given I assume you want to use two loops. The first, to iterate over all rows and the second to repeat your code n times.

```
for row in df.column_repetition:
    for i in range(row):
        print(i)
```

If you give us more information, we can probably come up with a better solution to your problem.